# Sufficient conditions for De Morgan's law in intuitionistic logic

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

What are the sufficient conditions for De Morgan's law $\lnot(P\wedge Q)\Rightarrow \lnot P \vee \lnot Q$ in intuitionistic logic?

If $P\vee \lnot P$ and $Q\vee \lnot Q$ are true, is it true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Under that assumption, you can examine the four cases. In three of the cases either $\lnot P$ or $\lnot Q$ holds, then $\lnot P\lor \lnot Q$ holds  you're done. In the other case, $P\land Q$ holds, and this contradicts the premise.

Comment: How do you prove $\lnot P \vee \lnot Q \vee (P\wedge Q)$ ?

Comment: $\lor$-elimination is a case-analysis rule. If you $A\lor B$ proven, and then you can prove the result both under the assumption of $A$ and then separately under the assumption of $B,$ then you can conclude the result. So if you have two $\lor$ statements $A\lor B$ and $C\lor D,$ then you have four cases to analyze: the one where $A$ and $C$ are true, then $(A,D), (B,C), (B,D).$

Comment: So, you don't prove that... the three disjuncts you wrote down are just three statements such that at least one of the three hold in each of the four cases. And each of the three separately suffices to prove the result. So along each of the four branches of the case analysis you can prove the result, hence it's proven.